# Configuring Hibernate Search with Infinispan and Wildfly

Tags: java, hibernate, wildfly, hibernate-search, infinispan

I'm configuring Hibernate Search 5.5.5 to use Infinispan 8.2.2 on Wildfly 10. 
I configured only the Infinispan module in Wildfly, not the Hibernate Search module.

Inside the persistence.xml I put this configuration:

```
<property name="hibernate.search.infinispan.cachemanager_jndiname" value="java:jboss/infinispan/container/hibernateSearch" />
<property name="wildfly.jpa.hibernate.search.module" value="none" />
```

This because seems that Infinispan is used, but doesn't persist the index.

All caches are configured in domain.xml as below:

```
<cache-container name="hibernateSearch" default-cache="LuceneIndexesData" jndi-name="java:jboss/infinispan/hibernateSearch" statistics-enabled="false">
      <replicated-cache name="LuceneIndexesMetadata" mode="ASYNC">
          <file-store fetch-state="false" passivation="false" preload="false" purge="false" shared="false" singleton="false"/>
      </replicated-cache>
      <replicated-cache name="LuceneIndexesLocking" mode="SYNC">
           <file-store fetch-state="false" passivation="false" preload="false" purge="false" shared="false" singleton="false"/>
      </replicated-cache>
      <replicated-cache name="LuceneIndexesData" mode="ASYNC">
           <file-store fetch-state="false" passivation="false" preload="false" purge="false" shared="false" singleton="false"/>
      </replicated-cache>
 </cache-container>
```

in jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
<module name="org.infinispan" slot="ispn-8.2"/>
<module name="org.hibernate.search.orm" services="export" />
```

When I try to index all I receive this error:

```
UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.Object is not an indexed entity or a subclass of an indexed entity
```

But If I remove this line:

```
<property name="wildfly.jpa.hibernate.search.module" value="none" />
```

I got

```
org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: Wrong configuration of directory provider: class org.infinispan.hibernate.search.spi.InfinispanDirectoryProvider does not implement interface org.hibernate.search.store.DirectoryProvider
```

The problem seems the same described here:

https://developer.jboss.org/thread/271789

But I don't find any working solution, and I'm sure that I havent one or more Infinispan or Hibernate version in my classpath.

What is wrong? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> TLDR; You are having 2 Infinispan versions in your classpath: one in your `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` and one coming with `org.jboss.as.clustering` subsystem.

## Custom Hibernate Search

`<property name="wildfly.jpa.hibernate.search.module" value="none" />` just means *do not automatically **use AND export** app server "search" module for my app*.

Thus, `<module name="org.hibernate.search.orm" services="export" />` is redundant, it will be done automatically as soon as you put the correct module id for `wildfly.jpa.hibernate.search.module` instead of `none` or just remove the property to use the default search module.

The `none` option is there for situations, when you don't want to use the default or custom search module but bundle it within your app.

More details [WildFly 10 Docs - Using Hibernate Search](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-UsingHibernateSearch)

## Custom WildFly Infinispan subsystem

`<module name="org.infinispan" slot="ispn-8.2"/>` doesn't upgrade WildFly Infinispan subsystem. It only allows your app to directly use Infinispan as a library. The correct way would be one of:

- Easy: upgrade to Wildfly 10.1 (It comes with Infinispan 8.2 and Hibernate Search 5.5 by default)
- Hard: upgrade or modify `org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan` module to use custom Infinispan version
- Absurd: dump the cache infrastructure provided with WildFly and use your own bundled and configured within application